# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "authentication_cityhaldata" does not exist LINE 1: ...hentication_cityhaldata"

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm trying to perform migrations on my production server. I installed all packages and dependencies. However, I receive the message:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "authentication_cityhaldata" does not exist
LINE 1: ...hentication_cityhaldata"."url_for_interview" FROM "authentic...
```

I tried deleting all files from the migrations folder of the application and project, but it didn't help.

I then tried to create a migration only for the authenticator app by 'python manage.py makemigrations authentication' it didn't work properly.

What can I do to make the system allow me to create a makemigrations on the server?

My modes:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField, ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill
from decimal import Decimal
from django.utils.text import slugify
from dashboard.choices import PROVINCES_CHOICES



class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('Konto firmowe', 'Konto firmowe'),
        ('Konto indywidualne', 'Konto indywidualne'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    [..more fields here..]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['email', ]


class RecommendationsSystem(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner', verbose_name='Osoba pierwsza')
    [..more fields here..]


class SocialMediaUrl(models.Model):
    PERCENT_RANGE = [
        (0.05, '5 procent'),
        # (0.10, '10 procent'),
        # (0.15, '15 procent'),
        # (0.20, '20 procent'),
        # (0.25, '25 procent'),
        # (0.30, '30 procent'),
        # (0.35, '35 procent'),
        # (0.40, '40 procent'),
        # (0.45, '45 procent'),
        # (0.50, '50 procent'),
        # (0.55, '55 procent'),
        # (0.60, '60 procent'),
        # (0.65, '65 procent'),
        # (0.70, '70 procent'),
        # (0.75, '75 procent'),
        # (0.80, '80 procent'),
        # (0.85, '85 procent'),
        # (0.90, '90 procent'),
        # (0.95, '95 procent'),
    ]
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    [..more fields here..]


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated_at',]




class CityHalData(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Nazwa urzedu miasta')
    [..more fields here..]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        CityHalData.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(slug=slugify(self.name + '-id-%s' % (self.pk)))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```